# How to access user control properties from a ResourceDictionary file

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, prism

Im using DevExpress and Prism in my application which Im new to both. Im trying to access "MyText" in the content item I create in my viewmodel. Currently when this item is created in CreatedSelectionEventReceived() via the viewmodel I don't see this property show up in my parameter list while debugging. I would like to know how to access this once its been created so I can update the property when a property is updated NumGaugeValue via the viewmodel. Right now I can hard code a value for "MyText" but unable to bind to it.

ResourceDictionary.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
x:Class="MyProject.WPF.Resources.CustomShapes"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
xmlns:dxc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/charts"
xmlns:dxdiag="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/diagram"
xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
xmlns:dxga="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/gauges"
xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:MyProject.WPF.Controls"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.WPF.ViewModels">
<Style x:Key="NumGaugeContentItem" TargetType="dxdiag:DiagramContentItem">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ctrl:NumberGauge MyText="22"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

MyView.xaml

```
<dxdiag:DiagramControl
                        x:Name="Diagram"
                        Width="{Binding ElementName=Dashboard, Path=ActualWidth}"
                        Height="{Binding ElementName=Dashboard, Path=ActualHeight}"
                        AllowAddRemoveItems="True"
                        AllowMoveItems="True"
                        AllowResizeItems="True"
                        CanvasSizeMode="Fill"
                        GridSize="25,25"
                        MaxZoomFactor="1"
                        MinZoomFactor="1"
                        ScrollMode="Content"
                        SelectedStencils="BasicShapes"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        ShowRulers="False"
                        ShowSelectionRectangle="False"
                        SnapToGrid="True"
                        SnapToItems="False"
                        ZoomFactor="1" />
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Drop">
                            <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DiagramControlDropCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type dxdiag:DiagramControl}}}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
 public class MyViewModel: BindableBase
{
   public string NumGaugeValue
    {
        get { return _numGaugeValue; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _numGaugeValue, value); }
    }
   private DiagramControl DiagramCtrl { get; set; }
   private Point CtrlPlacementCoordinates { get; set; }

   public DelegateCommand<string> UpdateCommand { get; set; }
   public DelegateCommand<DragEventArgs> DiagramControlDropCommand { get; set; }

   public MyViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        UpdateCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Execute).ObservesProperty(() => NumGaugeValue);  
        DiagramControlDropCommand = new DelegateCommand<DragEventArgs>(HandleDropOnDxDiagram);
        ItemSelectionCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(ProcessSelectionCommand);
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<ControlSelectionEvent>().Subscribe(ControlSelectionEventReceived);
    }

   public MyViewModel() { }

   private DiagramContentItem CreateDiagramItem(string styleId, Point position)
    {
        var ctrlItem = new DiagramContentItem() {CustomStyleId = styleId, Position = position};
        return ctrlItem;
    }

  private void HandleDropOnDxDiagram(DragEventArgs sender)
    {
        DiagramCtrl = (DiagramControl)sender.Source;
        CtrlPlacementCoordinates = sender.GetPosition(DiagramCtrl);
    }

    private void DoDragDrop(object sender)
    {
        // Grab the control from the accordion item and store as the control that was dropped
        var item = (AccordionItem)sender;
        var controlDropped = (ControlType)item.Items[0];

        if (controlDropped.DataContext != null)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(controlDropped, controlDropped.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }

  private void ControlSelectionEventReceived(ControlSelectionMessageInfo controlName)
    {
        // Create the control that was selected dynamically
        switch (controlName.SelectedControlName)
        {
            case "NumberGauge":
                var numGauge = CreateDiagramItem("NumGaugeContentItem", CtrlPlacementCoordinates);
                DiagramCtrl.Items.Add(numGauge);
                break;
            //other cases here but not relevant
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What error/exception do you get? What behaviour is missing? What behaviour do you want to see?

Comment: @Haukinger I updated my post...Im looking to access properties in the item Im creating from my resource file in which I reference a user control from. Im unsure how to do this successfully as I dont see "MyText" show up in my list of properties while in debugger.